# Eclipse Android: I want a letter appear firstly bigger and then getting smaller

Tags: android, eclipse, animation

In my activity is a TextView with the content "Ecl pse", where the "i" is missing. After I click on a button I want the letter "i" to appear in the right Position. But the "i" should be so animated, that it firstly appears a little bit bigger and then gets smaller until it is as big as the the other letters after I clicked on the button. But momentarily with my code the whole word "Ecl pse" is influenced by the ValueAnimation. It's not only that the "i" is bigger and gets smaller after I clicked on the button, but also the position of the whole word "Ecl pse" changes: "Ecl pse" goes down and then comes back in the origin position. How can i fix that? Again, I want only the letter "i" to appear a little bit bigger and then getting smaller until it is as big as the other letters of the word "Ecl pse" after I clicked on the button...

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvhallo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:text="Ecl pse"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnKlick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Klick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvhallo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvhallo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BtnKlick"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/BtnKlick"
        android:text="i"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE:

```
public Button btn;
    public TextView tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagetwo);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhallo);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);}

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
        animator.setDuration(2000);
        animator.setObjectValues("Ecl pse", "Eclipse");

        animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<CharSequence>()
        {
            @Override
            public CharSequence evaluate(float fraction, CharSequence startValue, CharSequence endValue)
            {
                float relativeSize = 4 - 3 * fraction;
                Spannable span = new SpannableString("Eclipse");
                span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(relativeSize), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                return span;
            }
        });

        animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
            {
                tw.setText((CharSequence)animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        animator.start();}}
```

Comment: use either a span or make one using Html and `<font size="...">` on your first letter.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) is the right instrument for what you're trying to achieve. It is both overkill and inadequate for the job. It can display all matters of text with various formatting and is for a good reason described as "a complete text editor". It's main purpose is to provide a way to display text, and possibly quite a lot of it (that part was the overkill). Inserting and (potentially) scaling the 'i' will cause the rest of the letters to move, as that is what the class is for. It's intended to layout text, not layout it statically in a way that causes changes to the content to move as little as possible (this is the inadequate part)

But what you actually want is not to display text, but an animation. I would recommend you create the text you want in any imaging program with various states: one without the 'i', a few with it too large and scaling down, and a final image with the correct proportions. Now use these images do display the animation triggered by pressing the button. I believe the correct class for this task would be [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), though I haven't used it myself. There are certainly numerous ways on how to get the exact behavior you want, but I hope this'll get you started!